# prevent angular template from being evaluated by browser

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have a src attribute of and img element which is being filled with an angular template, like this:

```
<img src="img/data/{{row.image}}" />
```

And whenever I browse the page I get the following 404 error from the browser:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/img/data/%7B%7Brow.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there some way to prevent the browser from trying to fetch the image until the template is resolved?

Comment: use ng-src="img/data/{{row.image}}"

Comment: Thanks a lot @squirod, it worked great, add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-src

```
<img ng-src="img/data/{{row.image}}" />
```